# passing value to form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-framework3

I'm not quite sure about the way of doing.
The challenge:
I call an addAction which shows a form. The point of calling the addAction gives two routing parameters, say value1 and value 2 separated by an "-".
I need value 1 and value 2 to search a pk in a table which will be saved as a foreignkey value by the addAction. I take both values give it to a method and get the key I need, that is tested and ok so far.

My problem.
In the first call of addAction I get the routing parameters and find the key. But afterwards of course it is forgotten. How can I remember the found value, so that I can use it for my saveModel method?

What would be the best way?
**Idea 1:**
Can I give it to the form and set it as value to the hidden keyfield?
For example:

```
class PadForm extends Form
{
public function __construct($name = null, $unitpartid)
        {

            parent::__construct('pad');



        $this->add([
                'name' => 'UnitPartPadID',
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'value' => $unitpartid,
        ]);
```

Would this be working? And would this be an accepted, proper way?

**Idea 2:**
Or would I try to use an instance variable in my controllerclass, like `$this->smtg;` ?

In both cases I get an understandable error

> Trying to get property of non-object

Questions:

what would be the best way?
and
how to do it, perhaps somebody could give a short example.

EDIT:
I really would appreciate to learn about the best way. I now tried to give a variable to my form and then fill in some field, but that doesn't work.

Part of Controlleraction
(the action works if I set a constant value for the related field)

```
$parameter = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
            //      echo $parameter;
                    $partnumber =substr($parameter,0,strpos($parameter,"-"));
           //       echo $partnumber;
                    $unitid=substr($parameter, strpos($parameter,"-")+1, strlen($parameter));
           //       echo $unitid;
                    $test=$this->unitparttable->getUnitPartID($unitid, $partnumber);
                    echo $test->UnitPartID;

                    $form = new PadForm(NULL, $test->UnitPartID);
```

Then in the Formclass:

```
 public function __construct($name = null, $unitpartid)
    {
        // We will ignore the name provided to the constructor
        parent::__construct('pad');
    //  $this->db=$db;


        $this->add([
            'name' => 'UnitPartPadID',
            'type' => 'hidden',           //hidden

        ]);


        $this->add([
                'name' => 'UnitPartID',
                'type' => 'text',           //hidden
                'value' => $unitpartid,
        ]);
```

The question is now, how to fill the formfield UnitPartID with the value of $unitpartid given within the constructor.
I also tried $form->populate but it is unknown, I used it in ZEND1 before, but probably it doesn't exist anymore.

any help appreciated!

Comment: Are you calling saveModel in the same controller action as you process the form data? It might help if you edited your question to include the controller part of your code.

Comment: but the saveModel method is not the question, it works. The question is how to keep the parameters passed by routing.